# Is martensitic steel 455 magnetic?

Tags: steel, magnets

According to wikipedia there are 3 types of steel based on the crystal structure: austenitic, ferritic and martensitic. Austenitic steels are non-magnetic where 300 series stainless steels belong to. Ferritic steels have magnetic properties. But I didn't manage to find any information about martensitic steel magnetic properties.

In particular I am interested in stainless steel alloy 455. According to the data I have this steel is magnetic (though didn't manage to find the source of this data). But when I obtained a sample of this steel It appeared to be non-magnetic. This brings to possibilities: either my source is wrong or the sample I got is not steel 455.

---

Upd.
Turned out that the samples I got were “accidentally” made of austenitic steel 304 instead of requested 455.

Comment: Did your sample come with a material certificate? And in what state is your sample 455; Hardened, Annealed, tempered.. etc.?

Comment: No. I guess I should request something like this. It is not the sample of material but a part made out of it.

Comment: Did you try an electro-magnet and/or a permanent magnet to test if it’s magnetic?

Comment: @GisMofx yes it has no effect

Comment: It depends how much austenite does it still have in its microstructure, you can probably find it by tracing the isothermal transformation diagram of the alloy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Any type of martensitic steel will be ferro magnetic. However the magnetic susceptibility may not be the same as that of a material like iron. This could make a sample look like it is not magnetic or very weakly magnetic when compared to a material with high magnetic susceptibility like iron. There is also the possibility that the sample has been worked in such a way that the magnetic susceptibility was reduced.

I would first make sure you are checking the sample with a strong magnet like a neodymium magnet. Otherwise, the manufacturer of the sample will know what has been done to the steel and how to best answer you question.

See [this article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7ciwBO5U08MJ:ispatguru.com/martensitic-stainless-steels/+&cd=14&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for more information about martensitic stainless steel magnetic properties and [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility) for information on magnetic susceptibility.

Answer (score 1):

This is a precipitation hardening martensitic so will be ferromagnetic unless it has been mistreated. To anneal, it is quenched from high temperature and makes a soft martensite = ferromagnetic. It is then machined and/or cold formed . And then final heat-treatment is an age at roughly 1000 F when it will harden. There may be minor changes in ferromagnetic properties depending on condition but I expect it is always similar to conventional steel. I never worked with it but the high nickel - 9%, makes it prone to have retained austenitic ( very low ferromagentism) structure after quenching: If so, a sub zero cooling ( like dry ice and alcohol) may get it to transform to martensite.

Comment: You can find information under" Carpenter 455".